# How to copy matplotlib figure?

Tags: python, wxpython, copy, matplotlib

I have `FigureCanvasWxAgg` instance with a figure displayed on a frame. If user clicks on the canvas another frame with a new `FigureCanvasWxAgg` containing the same figure will be shown. By now closing the new frame can result in destroying the C++ part of the figure so that it won't be available for the first frame.

**How can I save the figure?** Python deepcopy from copy module does't work in this case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "By now closing the new frame can result in destroying the C++ part of the figure" This should be avoidable somehow, e. g. by catching the close event and adapt it's behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the inner workings, but could easily imagine how disposing of a frame damages the figure data. Is it expensive to draw? Otherwise I'd take the somewhat chickenish approach of simply redrawing it ;)